# How can I make these 'Contact Form' fields required?

Tags: php, forms, contacts

```
<?php
$youremail  = "info@mainmanfilms.com";
$author   = $_POST['author'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$subject   = $_POST['subject'];
$text   = $_POST['text'];


if($send = "yes") {
    $content    = "Thank you for contacting Main Man Films!
```

Established in 1999, Main Man Films is a coalition of international producers, writers, directors, actors and technicians active in the TV / Film Industry. MMF is linked directly to notable talent (actors, producers, musicians, composers, etc.) and other industry professionals including distributors and syndicators. Whether you have an idea, completed script or a 'produced' program our team can assist you with taking your project from concept to distribution. MMF has produced projects in the United States, Japan, Belize, England and co-produced projects in South Africa, Bahrain and Singapore.";

```
    $headers    = "From: $email";
    @mail($email, 'Mail Notification | Main Man Films', $content, $headers);
}
    $headers    = "From: $email";
    $content = "Hello there! This is a message from your contact form.\r\n
    \r\n
    Name: $author\r\n
    E-mail: $email\r\n
    Subject: $subject\r\n
    \r\n
    Message: $text\r\n\r\n";
    $send = mail($youremail, 'Message from your contact form', $content, $headers);
    if($send)    {
        header("location:contact-form-thank-you.html");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        header("location:error.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: `if empty($author){echo 'fill it in';}`

Answer (score 2):

assuming the fields in question are author, email, subject and text, then you would run a validation script for each one to make sure there is content in them

```
$error = array();
if(empty($_POST['author'])) $error[] = 'Please enter author';

if(count($error)==0) {

//run script

}
```

So first you set an error variable as an array, and whenever any validation fails, you add to the array, and if there are no errors in the array, you run the script.

Comment: the validation doesn't have to be "empty" either, you can use anything, such a preg_match for the email address, or minimum characters for the author, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  As I am new to php, where exactly would I place this code?

Comment: Going by the code you wrote, it would be after you create the variables from the form submission, and then if there are no errors, you would run the rest of the script. But if there are errors you could then print them all out for the user to see, as they are stored in the array.

Comment: Thank you.  I modified the code but am not sure if it is properly done.  I do not receive an error message but the form still allows me to send without filling in the fields.

Comment: then you are not doing it right. 
1. The only way the form will send is if there are no errors, assuming that you placed your code in the //run script area that I did above.
2. The site will only show errors if you echo them out, e.g. foreach($errors as $error) echo "<p>$error</p>"